# how to pass variable outside then function with casperjs

Tags: javascript, variables, casperjs

I'm using casperjs to fetch some data
and I use variable inside funtion , but I can't use that variable outside that function

```
var website = 'test.com/index.php?id=';

casper.then(function () {
    var var1 = this.getElementAttribute('input[type="text"][name="var1"]', 'value');
    var var2 = this.getElementAttribute('input[type="text"][name="var2"]', 'value');
    var var3 = this.getElementAttribute('textarea[name="var3"]', 'value');
    var fullprint = (var1 + ', ' + var2 + ', ' + var3);

    this.echo(fullprint);
});

var4 = (website + var2); // how to use var2 here in another then function

casper.thenOpen(function (var4) {
    // some codes here
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I can't use that variable outside that function

You can't do so, because in JavaScript functions define a scope. Variables defined in this scope can be accessible by inner scopes (e.g you define a couple of functions inside your function), but are inaccessible from outer scopes.

You could create a separate function (actually this is not needed for that you are looking for, but I think it's more readable the code this way) for getting the values you want, like below:

```
function getInputValue(varName){
    return document.getElementAttribute('input[type="text"][name="'+varName+'"]', 'value');
}
```

Then you could change your code like below:

```
// At this object you could define properties 
// that you would like to use in many places in your code.
var values = {};

casper.then(function () {
    var var1 = getInputValue("var1");
    var var2 = getInputValue("var2");
    values.var2 = var2;
    var var3 = getInputValue("var3");
    var fullprint = (var1 + ', ' + var2 + ', ' + var3);

    this.echo(fullprint);
});

casper.thenOpen(function (var4) {
    var website = 'test.com/index.php?id=';
    var4 = website + values.var2;
    // some codes here
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: this this but its not working with me, I have to use the variable inside the function (before exit the function), I was able to csaper.thenopen it successfully

Answer (score 0):

You would need to declare `var2` in a scope that is accessible to each of the inner functions from which you want to access it from.